# Saving on a play SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I just started an internship position this week and I have to learn SQL to do my project. Problem is, the only server they have access to is not something I can really play around with and learn.

I asked if there was any way to make a database locally and they just told me I can add tables on to the already set up databases. I am not allowed to do anything else on it other than queries and the lesson I'm working with uses other functionalities. I can't get my program to work correctly and I'm sure the limited functionality I have has to do with it.

I would like to learn as much as possible before they are ready for me to start the actual project.

Comment: You can install a local database to your machine to play around in.  This comes standard with SSMS.

Comment: Can't you install SQL Server Express locally?

Comment: Another issue is I don't have the permissions to install anything. I'm sure I can get them,  but I wanted to see if there was a way around it?

Comment: Are you using SSMS to connect to the database?  If you have SSMS installed on your machine, you should already have a local database instance.  Try connecting to `localhost`.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, however connecting to Localhost gives me an error saying it was not found.

Comment: For localhost, should I use Windows authentication or is there a certain user and password I can use?

Comment: If it's a local user name and password then that's entirely at the whim of whomever installed it - there is no 'default' username or password. If using Windows authentication then that depends on if your account was added during installation or later configuration.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to message the guy that set up my laptop. He didn't seem to know about a localhost yesterday and he doesn't want me installing anything else so idk what they want me to do.

Comment: If `netstat -an | findstr 1433` doesn't find something, there's little chance your machine has a default SQL Server instance on it you don't know about.  (which would be unlikely anyways if you installed the client tools yourself and didn't choose a server instance)  Even a "non-default" instance would probably show up in `services.msc`.  (Anything with SQL in the name is worth checking)

Comment: @ebyrob looks like I don't have anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download SQL Server Express Edition here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express.  Why not install it on your PC at home?  You can then login as sa and do whatever you want.  I have it installed on my PC at home.  It is free.

It is worth noting that SQL Server Express does not have all the features of SQL Server Standard/Enterprise.  If you require the full set of features then you can buy SQL Server Developer Edition: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/application-development.  The Developer Edition is like the Enterprise edition, but for developers.  I believe you can get it for less than £50.

Comment: As the OP stated earlier: "Another issue is I don't have the permissions to install anything."

Comment: @Rachel Ambler, I am suggesting that it is installed on her own PC.  Then she "can really play around with and learn.".

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't installed. I wish it was! I was told yesterday "please don't install anything" so I'm in a pickle. I'd have to request for the rights anyway and I think I might need something showing I am allowed to install it too. It's a little different than my last internship and a little frustrating to be honest.

Comment: @Amber ask them to install it for you.

Comment: @Amber Rebecca Howe, I am suggesting that you install it on a PC that you own.  Then you do not have to seek permission.  You can learn SQL whenever you want.

Comment: @w0051977 that's kind of where I'm leaning towards, too. The only thing kind of keeping me from doing that is that learning SQL is my job right now and I want to have something to actually do during work. Is it acceptable to bring a personal laptop to a professional job??

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe It's an internship.  Don't be surprised if you have to follow along at home with some tools of your own...  However using personal hardware on work-time is generally not good.  If you feel you don't have enough to work on or you don't understand how they want to you learn SQL, you really need to speak with your direct supervisor.  In the first week, something like this might be normal.  If it drags beyond that worry.

Comment: I can't answer that question.  It is between you and your employer.  I would explain my reasons and see what they say.  They may even be more accommodating if you show initiative e.g. give you the access you require.  However, they may also be a bit sceptical about giving a beginner the freedom to do "really play around".

Comment: Thanks for all the insight, guys! I really appreciate it. I'll likely do some homework at home (especially because it's a 3 day weekend) and talk to them next week if I don't make it through all the lessons. In the mean time I'll just get done what I can at work. I'm sure I can go through most of the SQL lessons without any major problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally not played around with these, but I keep hearing good things about them: Microsoft Virtual Labs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/

From what I understand, whilst designed for specific purpose, they might be flexible enough to try other concepts on as well.

Worth a short, perhaps?